# Remove “email address” field from stripe checkout - angular 2

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I'm working in angular 2

How to Remove email address field from stripe checkout?

[image]

thx!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove the email field from Checkout. If you have an email already, you can pre-populate it by passing

`data-email="someone@example.com`

Or, if using Custom Checkout, `email: "someone@example.com"`

If you'd like to build a form without an email field I'd recommend trying Elements, https://stripe.com/docs/elements